# Jenkins pipeline Declarative syntax configuring checkout scm (path specific build triggers)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline (Declarative syntax) and would like to configure the pipeline to use scm trigger so build runs only when part of the git repo got changed.

I looked at the (pipeline plugin)[https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch-] documentation, the sample seems to be for scripted file syntax.  Comment down below says it works for dsl as well but couldnt find a proper sample usage.

Looking at the pipeline log I see an automatic step that gets the commit.

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
```

So is this being done automatically ?

I tried the following step, which seems to sync the code.

```
stage("Checkout ") {
    steps {
        checkout(scm)
    }
}
```

but not sure how to get this working for my use case i.e to ensure the pipeline to run only when a specific path in the source repo is changed like includedRegion here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a webhook for your source code management. Such a webhook will trigger jenkins to execute your pipeline. Then Jenkins will automatically get the newest version of your repo so source code checkout is enabled by default.

Comment: Webhook in bitbucket triggers the build. But I want the job to be triggered only when a specific path is modified. not for any changes in the repo